# Show that if $[E : F] = 2$, then $E$ is a splitting field over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, splitting-field

At present, I know this might involve the Factor Theorem/Division Algorithm in $E[x]$ and finding a root in the splitting field $E$, such that the root is not in $F$. Could anyone please elaborate further? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Comment: @Berci If the characteristic of $F$ is $2$ that formula is not valid.

Comment: Well, yes.. $\,\!$

Answer (score 6):

This area is not my strength, so there may be problems with this answer, but I thought I would give my ideas anyway in case they might be helpful:

Let $F \subseteq E$ be a field extension.  Suppose $[E:F] = 2$.  We want to show $E$ is the splitting field of some polynomial over $F$.

Since $[E:F] = 2$, we have that $\{1, \alpha\}$ is a basis for $E$ as a vector space over $F$, where $\alpha$ is a specific element of $E - F$.  Note that this means we can write $E = F(\alpha)$.  Then, since $\alpha^{2} \in E$, we have $\alpha^{2} = f_{1} + f_{2} \alpha$ for some $f_{1}, f_{2} \in F$, i.e., $\alpha^{2} - f_{2} \alpha - f_{1} = 0$.

Then since $\alpha$ is a root of $h(x) = x^{2} - f_{2}x - f_{1}$ which is a polynomial in $F[x]$, and $h$ is a degree 2 polynomial, it must be that this polynomial splits in $E$.  However, it doesn't split in $F$ since $\alpha \not \in F$.

Comment: Yes, but *why* degree=2 implies that 'it must split in $E$'? Basically this is the question.

Comment: @Berci I was thinking by the division algorithm.  $(x - \alpha)$ is a factor of $h(x)$, and this factor is in $E[x]$, so the other factor must be, as well.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @Berci I've thought more about this.  We have that $(x - \alpha)$ is a factor of $h(x)$ and so by the division algorithm, there is some $q(x) \in E[x]$ such that $h(x) = (x - \alpha)q(x)$.  But $q(x)$ must have degree $1$ since $h$ has degree $2$.  So $q(x)$ is of the form $(x - \beta)$ for some $\beta$, and thus $h(x)$ splits in $E = F(\alpha)$.

Comment: I think this answer makes the most sense, thanks @user46944 :) Thank you everyone too. The Factor Theorem implies that the remainder will be zero, so two linear factors.. hence two roots, hence satisfying the definition of a splitting field.

Comment: OK, I am convinced too

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{1,\alpha\}$ be a basis of $E$ over $F$. Then, from $F\subset F(\alpha)\subseteq E$, we get 
$$2=[E:F]=[E:F(\alpha)]\,[F(\alpha):F]$$
and so, since $[F(\alpha):F]>1$, we have $F(\alpha)=2$ and $F(\alpha)=E$.

Thus the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $2$ over $F$, let it be $X^2-sX+p$. Since this polynomial factors in $F(\alpha)[X]$ as $(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)$, we have that $\beta=s-\alpha\in F(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have $E=F$; for that would imply $|E:F
|=1$. Hence choose some $u\in E\backslash F$. Then by Tower's law:

$2=|E:F|=|E:F(u)||F(u):F|$.

Since $|F(u):F|=2$, we must have $|E:F(u)|=1$ and so $E=F(u)$.

The nice thing about the above is that, replacing $2$ by a prime $p$, then if $|E:F|=p$ then $E=F(u)$ for some $u\in E$.

Therefore the degree of the minimal polynomial $m$ of $u$ in $F$ is $2$.

Now just show that $m$ must contain all of its roots in $F(u)$.

Comment: I do not agree with your last sentence - take for instance $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $E = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.